# Proof systems that may be stronger than extended Frege?

Tags: reference-request, proof-complexity

The extended Frege proof system is thought to be a fairly strong proof system, with no known superpolynomial lower bounds. But I wonder, if extended Frege is proved not to be polynomially bounded one day, what can we do to continue pursuing the solution to the $\mathsf{NP}\overset{?}{=}\mathsf{coNP}$ problem? I think it's necessary to identify stronger proof systems. For example, the set theory $\mathrm{ZFC}$ may be stronger than extended Frege. So, my question is: what are the proof systems that we know to be possibly stronger than extended Frege, and what are the currently known results about the complexity relations between them and extended Frege? Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at standard basic literature? See in particular §4.6 and §14.1 in Krajíček’s 1995 book and §4, §7.3, and §12 in his 2019 book.